# Oracle APEX - Setting a value from Interactive Report column to a Item

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created a dashboard with an interactive report (APEX 4.2), in the report i am displaying a info column which displays whether the record has an attachments or not. If i click the link it will pop-up a modal window (i am using jquery window to display the list of attachments in a classical report). But the problem is, i am not able to set the record_id in the modal window hidden item to retrieve the corresponding attachments.

Somebody, please throw a light how to set the value the dynamically from Interactive report to the value to the Hidden item attached to the modal window.

Thanks
Sudhakar

Comment: If you use some javascript to open modal window, why not try line of code like $x(Px_ITEM_NAME).value = 'value';

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a tutorial](http://rowantraining.blogspot.ro/2013/08/oracle-apex-42-creating-modal-window.html) that helped me with this problem.

Comment: I am using the same solution but it is not working in the scenario if i try to display classic report in the modal window based on tabular report column value in the main window